# 2-Pseudoprimes and output

Tags: maple

If `n` is a positive integer greater than 2 that satifies `modp(2^n-1,n)=1` and `n` is not prime, then `n` is called a 2-pseudoprime. Find all 2-pseudoprimes less than 2000, and for each pseudoprime, output the pseudoprime and the set of its prime divisors.

Here is what I have tried so far. By the way, this is using maple.

```
for n from 2 to 2000 do
    n, mod(2^n-1,n) isprime(n);
od;
```

I am not sure what else to do here.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a conditional statement, constructed using `if...then...fi` (or the more modern `if...then...end if`.)

If the condition is met, then the desired result could be printed.

```
for n from 2 to 2000 do
    if `mod`(2^n-1,n) = 1 and not( isprime(n) ) then
        print(n, map(expand,{op(ifactor(n))}));
    fi;
od;
```